# Чем заменить mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ранее работало вот это

```
$cnt_price = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `product_razdel`, COUNT(`product_razdel`) AS cnt FROM `".$db."`.`".$prefiks."products` GROUP BY `product_razdel`"))  or die(mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "\n");
```

решил немного обновиться, перешел на PHP 5.5, Mysql 5.6
теперь подключение PDO и кругом одни Deprecated

Подскажите пожалуйста, чем заменить эту строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничем. mysql_num_rows() - это это абсолютно бессмысленная функция, которая никогда не бывает нужна. Вместо того, чтоб запрашивать у базы данных кучу строк и потом считать их, надо сказать базе, чтобы она посчитала сама, и вернула готовый результат.

А в данном конкретном случае у нас еще и запрос делает кучу бессмысленных операций.

Если переписывать на PDO, то [подключение берем отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql), и дальше пишем

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_razdel) FROM `$db`.`{$prefiks}products`";
$cnt_price = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Я обязательно разберу это, я только учусь ))